# Unable to mount external drive or sshfs

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, sshfs, fuse

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2.

Here's what happens when I try to mount an external USB drive:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc1: Command-line `mount "/media/nick/MyPassportRed"' exited with non-zero exit status 21: mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdc1 is already mounted on /media/nick/MyPassportRed

 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

But it isn't mounted, and it's not in mtab:

```
nick-LenovoThinkServer% cat /etc/mtab
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/nick/PortableSSD ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2 0 0
```

Similarly, I cannot mount a network location with sshfs:

```
nick-LenovoThinkServer% sshfs 192.168.0.102:/ /mnt/Nick-MacBookAir
fuse: bad mount point `/mnt/Nick-MacBookAir': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Running df:

```
nick-LenovoThinkServer% df
df: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Transport endpoint is not connected
df: ‘/mnt/Nick-MacBookAir’: Transport endpoint is not connected
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            16401184         4  16401180   1% /dev
tmpfs            3283412      5076   3278336   1% /run
/dev/sda1      447676256 309264808 115647776  73% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           16417060        12  16417048   1% /tmp
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none            16417060     74620  16342440   1% /run/shm
none              102400        40    102360   1% /run/user
tmpfs           16417060        44  16417016   1% /var/tmp
/dev/sdb1      240232960  54234060 173772648  24% /media/nick/PortableSSD
```

Oddly enough, the sshfs mount shows up when I run the mount command, but the MyPassportRed USB drive doesn't:

```
nick-LenovoThinkServer% mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=16401184k,nr_inodes=4100296,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3283412k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0c8d68c5-084d-40a0-9d9a-9a007a555526 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=4k,mode=755)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /var/tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/nick/PortableSSD type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,stripe=8191,data=ordered)
192.168.0.102:/ on /mnt/Nick-MacBookAir type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Please. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the error message

> fuse: bad mount point `/mnt/Nick-MacBookAir': Transport endpoint is not connected

is due to the fact that the connection dropped at some point, but your system still keeps memory of the volume **as if** it were mounted, while it really is not. The other error message,

> mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdc1 is already mounted on /media/nick/MyPassportRed

suggests exactly the same thing. What you need to do is, first, to kill the sshfs processes, to forcefully unmount the mount points,

```
  sudo umount -l /path/to/mount/points
```

and now restart sshfs. Keep in mind you can avoid this hassle if you use the *reconnect* option to sshfs: from [the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs),

> **-o reconnect**
>   reconnect to server